# Why html source is different when I opened it from web browser and read it in Java?

Tags: java, html, parsing

I have a question about parsering online html page.

when I open html source from a web browser, I can see the data in there.

But when I read this html page from java. I can not reach the data.

after I saved this html file, and read it as local file,

then I am able to read the data from there.

I take eBay.com.au as a example.

//--------Example---------

target web page
URL:http://www.ebay.com.au/sch/i.html?_trksid=p3907.m570.l1311&_nkw=imac+27&_sacat=0&_from=R40

Here is my Java code

```
import org.htmlcleaner.CleanerProperties;
import org.htmlcleaner.TagNode;
import org.htmlcleaner.HtmlCleaner;
import java.net.URL;


public class HtmlCleanerTest
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        CleanerProperties props = new CleanerProperties();

        URL myURL = new URL("http://www.ebay.com.au/sch/i.html?_trksid=p3907.m570.l1311&_nkw=imac+27&_sacat=0&_from=R40");

        TagNode tagNode = new HtmlCleaner(props).clean(myURL);

        Object[] myNodes = tagNode.getElementsByAttValue("class", "s1", true, true);

        for(Object oNote : myNodes)
        {
            TagNode n = (TagNode) oNote;
            System.out.println(n.getText());

        }
    }
}
```

I can get each product price by using this code, but I expected to get sellers location info by using this. How do I do that?

//---RE-edited -------------------------------

I have found a way to solv my question, 
I posted it here for someone like me has same problem.
I am not saying it is best solution for this, but I hope it may give you a thought.
here it is.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import java.util.List;;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.ebay.com.au/sch/i.html?scp=ce0&_sacat=0&_from=R40&_nkw=imac+27&_pppn=r1&_rdc=1");

        driver.findElement(By.id("e1-14")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.name("Stores")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("e1-3")).click();

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

/*--------------
------END-------
--------------*/

I came to here with one question, what if HTML File come with Javascript, How do we grab data from it with Javascript complete executed. I guess I am not very good questioner.

Comment: Need code to answer question.

Comment: May I take eBay.au as a example? here is a link for Imac 27 [www.ebay.com.au](http://www.ebay.com.au/sch/i.html?_trksid=p3907.m570.l1311&_nkw=imac+27&_sacat=0&_from=R40), if I want to get seller location from this web page, how do I code for that?

Comment: *"I can get each product price by using this code, but I expected to get sellers location info by using this. How do I do that?"* - I'm afraid that part of the question isn't really answerable.  At least, nobody here is going to do that work for you.  What you have is a large complex string (scraped HTML).  You're asking us to figure out for you how to extract specific information form that string.  That's really your job.  If you have a specific piece of input which you are acting upon and it's producing unexpected output, we'll be happy to help.  But we won't do the screen scraping for you.

Comment: @Cameron: You... just asked for the thing you just said you'd never ask for.  I'm afraid that isn't what we do on Stack Overflow.  If your question is something like, "I'm parsing this specific string and can't seem to extract this specific value, here's how I'm trying to do it." then we'd be happy to help.  If your question is something like, "Someone go to this website for me, look at the source code for me, and come up with a way to parse out the information I want for me." then the question isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow.  Currently your question is a lot closer to the latter.

Comment: @David: Hello David, Sorry take so loong to respond your comment, I was busy to solv my question. Sometimes, people who are in very beginning level, they know what is the problem they face, they know what they expect for result, but they may have not clue for how to solv their question, or even how to start to ask for help. They are not trying to pass their job to anyone. They are just lost in their question. I think that is why people build up a place like here to guide people who lost in their question. I am just one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the page has some JavaScript code that is executed by the browser and loads more data to the page, after the HTML has been loaded. Reading only the HTML with Java does not execute the JavaScript, hence additional data is not visible in the stream.

Edit:
A library like HtmlUnit may help in solving the common problem of loading Ajaxified Html pages to a certain degree: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I think so. Is there anyway I can read Html Source after it is executed completely?

Comment: Not an easy way. You will need an embedded Web browser that can load a page, execute the JavaScript and give access to the resulting DOM. Never did this, but maybe things like Lobo are a starting point: http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp

Comment: Replace 'embedded' with 'headless' in my comment and have a look at HtmlUnit: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thank you. I see my post is -2, Guess I do not provide any example for my question. here is my example, [ebay link page](http://www.ebay.com.au/sch/i.html?_trksid=p3907.m570.l1311&_nkw=imac+27&_sacat=0&_from=R40), if I want to get product price by using jave, I can use some html parser like htmlcleaner, htmlparser, but I found I cannot get seller location, it is totally blank, when I try to reach it.

Comment: To get more positive feedback for future questions, post a runnable, self contained Java code example, along with the result and what you expected and why you expected it.

Comment: Okay, I will re-edit my question, I will post my code and result, and what I expected.  please check it later, Thank you so much.

Comment: On my side of the planet, it is time to sleep. Try out HtmlUnit or other libraries. If there are still problems, create a new question and close this one.

Comment: Okay, Thank you so much. Good Night.