# I got very different html source from online web page parsing by using java and web browser

Tags: java, html, html-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why html source is different when I opened it from web browser and read it in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214112/why-html-source-is-different-when-i-opened-it-from-web-browser-and-read-it-in-ja)

I have a question about parsing online html page. When I open html source from a web browser, I can see the data in there.

But when I read this html page from java. I can not reach the data.

After I saved this html file, and read it as local file, then I am able to read the data from there.

I take eBay.com.au as a example.

//--------Example---------

target web page
URL:http://www.ebay.com.au/sch/i.html?_trksid=p3907.m570.l1311&_nkw=imac+27&_sacat=0&_from=R40

Here is my Java code

```
import org.htmlcleaner.CleanerProperties;
import org.htmlcleaner.TagNode;
import org.htmlcleaner.HtmlCleaner;
import java.net.URL;

public class HtmlCleanerTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        CleanerProperties props = new CleanerProperties();

        URL myURL = new URL("http://www.ebay.com.au/sch/i.html?_trksid=p3907.m570.l1311&_nkw=imac+27&_sacat=0&_from=R40");

        TagNode tagNode = new HtmlCleaner(props).clean(myURL);

        Object[] myNodes = tagNode.getElementsByAttValue("class", "s1", true, true);

        for(Object oNote : myNodes)
        {
            TagNode n = (TagNode) oNote;
            System.out.println(n.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

I can get each product price by using this code, but I expected to get sellers location info by using this. How do I do that?

Comment: Things like "product price" and "sellers location" don't have any real meaning outside the context of your site scraping logic.  Can you be more specific?  When debugging your code, at what point does observed behavior deviate from expected behavior?  What are the runtime values of the objects when that happens?

Comment: it could be the user-agent. Web Designers have been known to program sites differently for different user-agents. You could try telling the website that you are IE and not a java call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data shown in the website is javascript generated, you will have no way to get the data unless you implements javascript functionality in your java code.

Second possibilities is the web server determine the data from the user-agent or the capabilities of the browser/fetcher.

Comment: You're wasting your time as this has already been answered in the original thread, and the original poster ignored that answer it seems. Otherwise he wouldn't be re-asking the very same question.

Comment: I was attempt to close the original poster, re edit it and post a new question. guess now both of posters are closed.

Comment: Every time I post a question, My Poster -2, I guess I do not know how to ask a question, if anyone can see what am I trying to ask, then please ask it for me. if not, never mind.